# Stop "Sign In To Set Up Office" window appearing in Shared Computer Activation environment

Tags: microsoft-office, office365, license, shared-access

I am trying to set up Shared Computer Activation as we have several 'Kiosk' style desktop PC's that are used by some staff with Microsoft 365 Business Premium, and other staff with Microsoft 365 Business Basic licenses.

We implement SSO for the Premium licensed users, so they are able to log in and activate without needing to enter credentials. The limited version of the apps are exactly what I need for the Basic licensed users (they just need to read Excel and Word files). However every time a Basic licensed user opens an Office app they are prompted to Sign In and Activate Office. They cannot sign in as their Business Basic license does not allow them to activate Office in this environment.

Is there any way to prevent the Sign In screen from appearing on each login?

Comment: According to "[How shared computer activation works for Microsoft 365 Apps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/overview-shared-computer-activation#how-shared-computer-activation-works-for-microsoft-365-apps)", if your environment is configured to synchronize Office 365 (Azure Active Directory) and local Active Directory (AD) accounts, then the user most likely won't see any prompts.

Comment: This is true for fully licensed (Business Premium) users, however I would like the Business Basic licensed users to also not see any prompts... I am fine with them using the restricted (read and print only) versions of apps as they dont need to do more, hence why they have Business Basic licenses!